# elasticsearch:update the doc if exists in all the shards of an index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

I googled on update the docs in ES across all the shards of index if exists. I found a way (/_bulk api), but it requires we need to specify the routing values. I was not able to find the solution to my problem. If does anybody aware of the below things please update me.

1. Is there any way to update the doc in all the shards of an index if exists using a single update query?.
2. If not, is there any way to generate routing values such that we should be able to hit all shards with update query?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally for bulk update, ES recommends get the documents by query which needs to get updated using scan and scroll, update the document and index them again. Internally also, ES never updates a document although it provides an Update API through scripting. It always reindexes the new document with updated field/value and deletes the older document.

```
Is there any way to update the doc in all the shards of an index if exists using a single update query?.
```

You can check the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) if its suits your purpose. Also there are plugins which can provide you update by query. [Check this.](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery)

Now comes the routing part and updating all shards. If you have specified a routing value while indexing the document for very first time, then whenever you update your document, you need to set the original routing value. Otherwise ES would never know which shard did the document resided and it can send it to any shard(algo based).

If you don't use routing value, then based on the ID of the document, ES uses an algo to decide the shard it needs to go. Hence when you update a document through a bulk API and keeps the same ID without the routing, the document will be saved in the same shard as it was previous and you would see the update.

Comment: piyushGoyal:my requirement need to update the doc with same id in whichever shard it exists as my routing value was different while inserting. scenario is a doc is shared among multiple users and routing value is userid during insertion and docid is id.

Comment: You can always get your previous routing value as part of metadata in 2.0

Comment: No. my requirement is diffrent. let there are 1 lakh users shared 1 doc and my index has 5 shards. then ideally i need to prepare 5 update querys instead of 1 lakh update querys as id of doc remain same but routing changes for each user.

Comment: I didnt get you buddy at all. What do you mean by 1 lakh users sharing same document? They access the same document? They have privileged to update the same document?